# Avoid possible statement with regex

Tags: php, regex

How to replace a part of string with avoid a year numbers (f.e. 2019 or 2019-2020) before the first slash occurance with Regex

```
//something is wrong here
preg_replace('/^[a-z0-9\-]+(-20[0-9]{2}(-20[0-9]{2})?)?/', '$1', $input_lines);
```

Needed:

<strike>abc-def/</strike>something/else/ [incl. slash if there is not character before it]

<strike>abc-def-</strike>2019/something/else/

<strike>abc-def-</strike>2019-2020/something/else/

<strike>abc-def-125-</strike>2019/something/else/

Comment: That is usually done like this [(?m)^(?:(?!20(?:19|20))\[a-z0-9\-\])+/?](https://regex101.com/r/j9qA27/1) Expanded https://regex101.com/r/5JT2Sk/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial closure was insufficient to handle all requirements.  Yes, you have a greedy quantifier problem, but there is more to handle.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/INSHr)) ([Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H2mZZO/1))

```
$tests = [
    'abc-def/something/else/',
    'abc-def-2019/something/else/',
    'abc-def-2019-2020/something/else/',
    'abc-def-125-2019/something/else/'
];

var_export(
    preg_replace('~^(?:[a-z\d]+-?)*?(?:/|(?=20\d{2}-?){1,2})~', '', $tests)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'something/else/',
  1 => '2019/something/else/',
  2 => '2019-2020/something/else/',
  3 => '2019/something/else/',
)
```

My pattern matches alpha-numeric sequences, optionally followed by a hyphen -- a subpattern than may be repeated zero or more times ("giving back", aka non-greedy, when possible).

Then the first non-capturing group must be followed by a slash (which is matched) or a your year substrings which also may have a trailing hyphen (this is not matched, but found via a lookahead).

If this doesn't suit your real projects data, you will need to provide more and more accurate samples to test against which reveal the fringe cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the forward slash has to be present and it should stop after the first occurrence of 2019 or 2020, you might use:

```
^(?=[a-z\d-]*/)[a-zA-Z013-9-]+(?>2(?!0(?:19|20)(?!\d))|[a-zA-Z013-9-]+)*/?
```

In separate parts that would look like

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[a-z\d-]*/)` Assert that a `/` is present
- `[a-zA-Z013-9-]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed (Note that the 2 is not listed)
- `(?>` Atomic group

  - `2(?!0(?:19|20)(?!\d))` Match 2 and assert what is on the right is not 019 or 020
  - `|` Or
  - `[a-zA-Z013-9-]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `/?` Match optional `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3WvyZb/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/HNTle)

Your code might look like

```
preg_replace('~^(?=[a-z\d-]*/)[a-zA-Z013-9-]+(?>2(?!0(?:19|20)(?!\d))|[a-zA-Z013-9-]+)*/?~', '', $input_lines);
```